# get data from combo box using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm just learning about jquery and ajax, trying to create combo box and get the data based on the combo box value

here is my code on index.php

```
 <form action="cari.php" method="post">
         <select name="kamar">                  
              <option value="regular single">Regular Single Rp 99.000</option>
              <option value="regular double">Regular Double Rp 120.000</option>
              <option value="family single">Family Single Rp 127.500</option>
              <option value="family double">Family Double Rp 150.000</option>
              <option value="vip single">V.I.P Single Rp 170.000</option>
              <option value="vip double">V.I.P Double Rp 200.000</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <br>

    <div id="tampil"></div>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
              loadData();

              $('form').on('submit', function(e)
              {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   $.ajax({
                      type: $(this).attr('method'),
                      url: $(this).attr('action'),
                      data: $(this).serialize(), 
                      success:function(){
                           loadData();
                      },
                   });
              })
         })

         function loadData(){
              $.get("tampil3.php", function(data){
                   $("#tampil").html(data)
              })
         }
    </script>
```

here for cari.php

```
<?php
     include "koneksi.php";
     $jenis = $_POST['kamar'];
     $sql= "select * from kamar where jkamar = '$jenis' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>
     <?php
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
          {
               while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
               {
               ?>
               <tr><?php echo $data['nokamar']; ?></tr>
          <?php 
               }
          }
          else
          {
               echo "no more data!";
          }
     ?>
</table>
```

tampil3.php, for getting all records from database

```
<?php
     include "koneksi.php";
     $sql= "select * from kamar";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<table border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2>
     <?php
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
          {
               while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
               {
               ?>
               <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $data['nokamar']; ?></td>
               </tr>
          <?php 
               }
          }
          else
          {
               echo "no more data!";
          }
     ?>
</table>
```

i already tried this code and its not working, any help?

any suggestion will be appreciated

thanks!

Comment: It could be because of missing <td> tag in this - <tr><?php echo $data['nokamar']; ?></tr>.  It should be - <tr><td><?php echo $data['nokamar']; ?></td></tr>

Comment: You have not specified parameter under your `success(..)` , change it to `success(data)` and the under that write `console.log(data);` and check if data is coming successfully or not . Also what does this `loadData();` do ?

Comment: @Swati : loadData(); is for loading all record from database,
for `console.log(data)` result, is the result of cari.php

Comment: so it just worked after i changed `success(...)` to 
`success:function(data){
 $("#tampil").html(data);
}`

thanks for help